# Run script on multiple schemas on PostgreSQL DB

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I need to run a huge migration script on multiple schemas on PostgreSQL 9.3 server. I want output to be in a .txt format if this failed on any schema. Would you be able to help me on this?

Details:
All schemas are of similar structure and I have the list of schemas on which this script needs to be executed.

Comment: Do you know how to use python and foreign data wrapper (FDW)? And those schemas are within same database, same cluster but different DBS, various clasters?

Answer (score 1):

You could run the following bash script. It will expect the list of schemas in the `schemas.txt` file, and your script in `myscript.sql`. It will run the script on each schema (as a default schema) in `mydatabase`, and will produce, for each schema, a file named `myscript-output-<the_schema_name>.txt`.

For Unix, the script is:

```
cat schemas.txt | while read schema; do
  (
    echo "SET search_path TO $schema,public;"
    cat myscript.sql
  ) | psql -f - -o myscript-output-${schema}.txt mydatabase
done
```

For windows, the script is (use `%%S` instead of `%S` when used in a batch file):

```
for /F %S in (schemas.txt) do @(
  echo SET search_path TO %S,public;
  type myscript.sql
) | "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\psql" -f - -o  myscript-output-%S.txt mydatabase
```

Comment: can we get this script on as a batch script.. our DB environment is on Windows.

Comment: @Vinod windows script added